# Why am I having conflicts during rebase when I am the only developer on my Github project?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am new to Git and tried Github to learn the new source control system and I am wondering why am I having conflicts after a rebase or even a merge when I am the only one contributing to it. Since I am the only dev, shouldn't my version of the source always be in 'sync' (no conflicts) with the one in Github?

Can you please explain to me what is causing the conflicts and if I can do something about it?

I am using egit in eclipse and my workflow is basically this.

edit => commit => rebase => push

P.S. I am only coding on one computer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no need for you rebase at all in this situation - that is what causes the conflicts because it rewrites your history. Just commit and push.

Comment: Sometimes when I just commit and push, I'm having the non-fast-forward errors

Comment: Try recloning locally and then only commit + push.

Comment: Can you give more detailed output about exactly what you doing (not just approximate workflow)? Include exact error messages.

Comment: added screenshots on my simple workflow. I just edited my TODO file, did a commit-and-push. committed, but push was rejected. that's why im doing a rebase. and sometimes, that rebase causes conflicts.

Comment: You see the message about the commit being amended? That means you are rewriting a previous commit (amending it) instead of making a new one. This is also rewriting your history and causing problems for commits you've already pushed. If you're starting out, don't amend or rebase, just do simple commits.

Comment: Also I refer all git newbies to this tutorial - it is great at helping you to understand what is happening when you do various git operations. http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Comment: The last couple times I've committed I've had merge errors, and I'm not doing any rebases. There must be something else that can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> I just edited my TODO file, did a commit-and-push. committed, but push was rejected. that's why im doing a rebase. and sometimes, that rebase causes conflicts.

It only creates conflict if there are concurrent modifications on the same file:

- local modifications (commits) done on your local branch
- remote modifications (commits) done on the remote Git repository hosting site, like GitHub: you can edit and commit directly there, using the Web UI.

In that case, a push will fail because your local and remote history have diverged.

A rebase is the best practice but... for common files modified both locally and remotely, can generate conflicts.
Once resolved, and once the rebase is completed, a `git push` will work.